# Usability of an email field without label "email"

Tags: input, email, input-fields, newsletter

Does it make sense to a user that this field is for email only?
Or is it confusing?

[image: subscription]

Comment: The wording is confusing as well, please review _Don't worry, !! we respect your privacy we never spam._
The use of punctuation is completely wrong. 
This conveys a sense of amauterish-ness. 
Speaking for myself I'd wonder if this is a scam or a legit website.

Comment: I really like the simplicity of forms, but guiding users is really important. I feel there is no "guide" here...

Comment: It's not very accessible as it is without a proper field label.

Comment: You should also consider the fact that the [placeholder attribute is not supported by all browsers](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder) so, unless you're using a jQuery plugin or other API to display it, it won't be there for users with pre-HTML5 browsers.

Answer (score 12):

It does need a label, not just visually for people viewing the site but for people using assistive technologies (screenreaders etc). If there is no label then people visiting do not know what the field is for, or what goes it it.

From W3C [Guideline 3.3 Input Assistance: Help users avoid and correct mistakes.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#minimize-error-cues)

> 3.3.2 Labels or Instructions: Labels or instructions are provided when content requires user input. (Level A)

Having no label means you don't even conform to the bare minimum accessibility standard.

Comment: A label is definitely required, but I believe the visibility of the label is more his question. As long as he has one and it's "linked" up appropriately using for and id attributes this design works fine.

Comment: @BillCriswell: Well if there is a label in the HTML saying it's an Email field that's good for such users, but what about sighted ones? What happens if I write my name in that field, how do I know that's not what the field is after? As the highly relevant phrase goes: "Don't Make Me Think".

Comment: You're right. It should ask for an email directly. I was more talking about the design of it, not really the wording. I wasn't clear enough. =)

Answer (score 3):

I would say give it a label.

Also, as a side note, "go" doesn't seem like the right CTA on the button. "Submit", "enroll" or "sign-up" would all be better options. "Go" implies you'll be moving the user to another page for next steps, while language that indicates this is a submission field would make more sense. If you actually *are* taking them to a page where you get more details, then don't ask for any information now, get them to the full form as simply as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the button text

> **Go**

with

> **Join** or **Join our mailing list**.

Because that is what the button is doing.
Put an example email like **your@email.com** on the textbox (or input), if thats a webapp you can safely use the `placeholder` element.

Replace

> Don't worry, !! we respect your privacy we never spam.

To

> We never spam.

Remember that you should provide an email validation.

If you still want to show the Email label, check how mailchimp solved this problem[image: Mailchimp]

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to imagine there would be some text somewhere around this field that would explain a little about your mailing list (e.g. how often to expect emails, what kind of content to expect, etc.). If not, you should really consider adding this. I struggle to imagine many visitors clamoring to enter something into a random field with very little context.

Once you have some copy about the mailing list within the context of that sign up field, the field itself becomes much less ambiguous and the significance of the label becomes much less critical.

I do agree with the general sentiment that a label is required, and the CTA should be clearer. With some copy to help provide context to the field, I can see something like this:

```
---------------------  ----------
| your email        |  |  JOIN  |
---------------------  ----------
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

[image]

The water mark can still be shortened without losing the meaning

Comment: it would be sweet to see a 2 line placeholder text.

Comment: I don't think this adds any value. It just makes the form field longer.